# R: Predict VAR with new data

Tags: r, var, predict

I try to forecast a timeseries using an estimated VAR model and new data of one of the two variables.

Assume a VAR of monthly DAX and Oilprice returns.

```
#Select variables for VAR model
MakroVAR <- as.data.frame(cbind(DAX=Makro_diff$DAX, OIL=Makro_diff$OIL))

#Estimate VAR model
var <- VAR(na.omit(MakroVAR), p=1, type="const", ic = "AIC")
```

Now I can use the predict function without providing new data.

```
# Predict VAR
pred.var1 <- predict(var, n.ahead = 12)
```

Now I want to provide a series of 12 new returns of DAX.

```
# New data for DAX
DAXnew <- data.frame(DAX=c(-0.0222, 0.0093, 0.0136, -0.0074, 0.0161, 
-0.0029, 0.0007, 0.0073, 0.0018, -0.0032, 0.0059, -0.0043))
```

But the predict function will always give the same results and seems to ignore the newdata.

```
# Predict VAR conditional on new DAX data
pred.var2 <- predict(var, newdata = DAXnew, n.ahead = 12)
```

I also tried providing both series with one NA and one with data, which always brings the same results.

My question is, in which way do I have to provide the new data for a VAR model to achieve that the second series will be calculated given the new data.

Comment: Which package are you using vor the `VAR` function?

Comment: I'm using the vars package

Comment: The package manual sais `...   Currently not used` and the newdata argument is not explicitly listed. Maybe it is not implemented ...

Comment: Oh, okay. Is there another way to forecast var models like this?

Comment: Sorry, I`m not realy into VAR modelling.

Answer (score 0):

The r package 'tsDyn' supports the use of newdata, whereas the 'vars' package does not.